# Setting up path Connector/J in windows 7

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Can anyone please tell me as to how to setup the path for Connector/j using the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar" in windows 7?
I'm using the below code and  it always end up throwing an exception. 
(java.lang.ClassNotFoundException : com.mysql.jdbc.driver)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
public class LoadDriver 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        try 
    {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
        System.out.println("Connection working");
        }
        catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        System.out.println("Connection Fail");
        System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
    }
    }
}
```

**I tried following the official documentation of connector/j for setting up the path, but could not understand.**

I tried adding E:\PROGRAM FILES\JAVA\jdk1.7.0_01\jre\lib\ext\mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar in the "path" environment variable, Please correct me.

Comment: using any ide like netbeans etc.

Comment: I'm trying to learn the basics by using editors only.

Comment: I followed this tutorial -> http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090201&page=4

and setup the classpath. 

Now my program runs fine. Thank you all for the input. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you dont need `newInstance` on `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")`

Second don't copy jars to your JDK folder, there shouldn't ever bee a need to copy them there. The correct thing to do is add the jar to your project as a dependency. If your not using an IDE, then you want to add the jar to java.exe as a --classpath option when you run your code (run "java.exe /?" for more details). If you're using eclipse, you should add the mysql jar to the project by clicking on the project and selecting "properties" and then "Java Build Path" there will be an "Add JARs..." button on the right. Then the IDE will add it to your classpath automatically.

Comment: @user93166 I'm not using IDE is there anyway of avoiding the -classpath parameter everytime while running using the "java" command?

Comment: I followed this tutorial -> http://www.stardeveloper.com/articles/display.html?article=2003090201&page=4

and setup the classpath. 

Now my program runs fine. Thank you all for the input. :)